# Will China's new encryption laws affect electronics exported to the USA?

Tags: united-states, privacy, international

China is about to roll out a new encryption law that will require the Chinese government "to seize all communications, data, and other information stored in electronic form that belong to foreign companies." ([reference](https://www.theepochtimes.com/chinas-new-encryption-law-poses-threat-to-us-companies-experts-warn_3178810.html)) The article referenced goes on to mention that VPNs will no longer be private, if even allowed, and even private servers may be prohibited. My question is how this new law will affect devices produced in China and exported to the US. For example, will OnePlus devices receive an OTA update that will contain a backdoor? What about Oppo, Lenovo, Huawei, and others?